# How to resolve this error 'int' object not iterable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, runtime-error

```
  def activityNotifications(expenditure, d):
      notif = 0
      if(d%2):
          x = math.floor(d/2)
          y = math.ceil(d/2)
          for i in range(d,len(expenditure)):
               if(sum(expenditure[i-x],expenditure[i-y])/2 <= expenditure[i]):
               notif+=1
      else:
          for i in range(d,len(expenditure)-1):
               if(expenditure[i - d/2] <= expenditure[i]):
               notif+=1
  return notif
```

File "Solution.py", line 16, in activityNotifications
        if(sum(expenditure[i-x],expenditure[i-y])/2 <= expenditure[i]):
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: `sum(expenditure[i-x],expenditure[i-y])` doesn't do what you think it does: alternative: `expenditure[i-x] + expenditure[i-y]`

Answer (score 1):

You should changes this line `if(sum(expenditure[i-x],expenditure[i-y])/2 <= expenditure[i]):`

It should be:

```
if(expenditure[i-x]+expenditure[i-y])/2 <= expenditure[i]:
```

Syntax of **sum** function:

**sum(iterable, start)**

- iterable : iterable can be anything list , tuples or dictionaries ,
  but most importantly it should be made of numbers.
- start : this start is added to the sum of 
  numbers in the iterable.

Answer (score -2):

`sum(expenditure[i-x],expenditure[i-y])` doesn't do what you think it does.

The first argument must be an *iterable* and the second (optional) argument is the start value (defaults to 0). Passing 2 integers to `sum` makes no sense.

If you *really* wanted to use `sum` you'd have to write:

```
sum(expenditure[i-a] for a in [x,y])
```

why making things complex (and underperformant) ? do:

```
if expenditure[i-x] + expenditure[i-y] <= expenditure[i]:
```